# Evaluate integral with Mathematica

Tags: improper-integrals, mathematica

I'm sorry, this is perhaps not the best question for this forum.

However, it would be of enormous help if someone could evaluate this integral for me using Mathematica or similar software.

Thank you very much!

$\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty e^{- t/\gamma}\left(t-\frac{1}{2\gamma}t^2\right) e^{-|t-t'|/\mu'}e^{- t'/\gamma}\left(t'-\frac{1}{2\gamma}t'^2\right) dtdt'$

Comment: This seems like a question for Mathematica SE instead. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $\gamma,\mu>0$, it is 
$$
\frac{\gamma^5\mu(\gamma+3\mu)}{8(\gamma+\mu)^3}
$$

Comment: Your answer is correct, however, could you tell me a bit more how you obtained it? If using Mathematica, could you provide a code? Sorry, about the late question, but this problem has just come up again!